# Alternative of cmds.xform in raw Python

Tags: python, maya

I have writen a code in Maya (python) which gives me the position of an object in Maya. As you can see in the first line , i import maya.cmds and in the second line I use it

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
a_end = cmds.xform('j_l_ankle', q=1, ws=1, t=1)
```

I would like to have the same output in basic python code without importing maya.cmds. That means I would like to find an **alternative of xform function** in baisc python.

Comment: what do you mean by basic python. You can get it by mayaApi but I don't see how you would communicate with maya without module

Comment: @DrWeeny I would like to get the similar output in clo3D ( another 3D software) . The above code in Maya allows me to get the world corrdinate. 

import maya.cmds as cmds


So in Clo3d I can NOT of course import maya module. So I am loooking for an alternative  that allows me to get the world coordinate of an object in basic python( without importing a module) so that I can implement in Clo3d(allows python script)

Comment: I dont know which is clo3d but you have to write your unified module that detect in which software you are and launch the appropriate command. So you can have the same def get_worldCoordinate for maya and clo3d

Comment: You would have to check documentation of Clo3d and find what function query's an object's transform. What you're asking for makes no sense. Of course there's no "generic" built-in Python function to get any given transform. Just think about it, that's why api's exists so that you can communicate with a software. Python on its own has no idea how to communicate with other softwares, and that's why you had to use maya's `cmds` api to use `xform`. Likewise you'll need to use Clo3d's api too.

Answer (score 1):

Python for Maya, which you can access via `maya.cmds` module, is a sort of **Python wrapper** for calling MEL methods. Literally, you are calling MEL methods using a sort of Python syntax. This gives you the benefit of using Python's libraries for manipulating data in Maya (`cmds.xform` isn't an exception).

Most Maya Embedded Language commands have been implemented into the `maya.cmds` module. But there are still some cases where only MEL must be used over Python, because Maya doesn't fully incorporate Python in all aspects of its architecture. And, I should say, that Autodesk Maya converts all of its MEL commands to Python procedurally.

So Python's `maya.cmds` module greatly depends on native MEL. The **Python bindings** for all of the native Maya commands are in the **`maya.cmds`** module. In order to access these commands, you must import `maya.cmds` in each session.

## `xform` command example:

MEL code:

```
sphere -n Earth;
xform -r -ro 0 0 45;
```

Python equivalent:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.sphere(n = 'Earth')
cmds.xform(r = True, ro = (0, 0, 45))
```

As you can see, you have to communicate with native MEL commands via `maya.cmds` module, when scripting using Python.